# grab text between two patern

Tags: c#

Check the code bellow. I want to grab everything between this `id="a-popover-sp-info-popover-` until `"`. I already tried to use following `Regex.Match` formula but there is syntax error. Its not valid in c#. How can i do this in proper way. My goal is to grab `ABC123` text.

```
string foo = @id="a-popover-sp-info-popover-ABC123";

string output = Regex.Match(foo, @"id="a-popover-sp-info-popover-(.*)"").Groups[1].Value;
```

i need to grab only text: `ABC123`

Comment: The way you define `foo` is not valid C#. Do you mean `string foo = "@id = \"a-popover-sp-info-popover-ABC123\"";`?

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden I guess this is what John meant when saying: "but there is syntax error.  Its not valid in c#."

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden yes now the foo is valid in c#. but how can i use it in `Regex.Match`?

Comment: I wonder whether you need regex at all. it seems like you simply need the rest of the string after `"a-popover-sp-info-popover-"` this could also be done using split. From your post it seems that the pattern is really fixed and always the same word.

Answer (score 1):

since your pattern is so rigid, actually the string.Split method could also do the trick:

```
string output1 = foo.Split(new string[] {"info-popover-"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Last()
                    .TrimEnd('"');
Console.WriteLine(output1);
```

Output:

> ABC123

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure to surround your strings with quotation marks ".
If you want to have quotation marks inside of your string you have to escape them with a backslash:

```
string foo = "id=\"a-popover-sp-info-popover-ABC123\"";

string output = Regex.Match(foo, "id=\"a-popover-sp-info-popover-(.*)\"").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
string pattern = "id=\"a-popover-sp-info-popover-[A-Z]{3}[1-9]{3}\"";
string input = "id=\"a-popover-sp-info-popover-ABC123\"";

Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

if (m.Success) Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}'", m.Value);
```